# What is soma mentioned in vedas?

Tags: vedas, rig-veda, soma

What is soma mentioned in vedas is it ritulastic drink it is said that it causes immortality but it is taken by humans too so is it devine knowledge as only the knoledge of **self** or both **self** and **impersonal self** can give immortality.
or it is used adjectively

[Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soma_(drink)) on soma gives—

> The references to immortality and light are characteristics of
>   an entheogenic experience.

Also,consider Rigveda (8.79.2-6) regarding the power of Soma:

> **"...He covers the naked and heals all who are sick. The blind
>   man sees; the lame man steps forth....Let those who seek find
>   what they seek: let them receive the treasure....Let him find what
>   was lost before; let him push forward the man of truth...."**

Such is indicative of an experience with an entheogen of
some source.

Comment: apparently you are not concerned with what Soma was physically.  the reference to entheogen seems irrelevant to what you are asking.

Comment: question is simple is it used for both physically and spritually or as an adjective.